# C++ help concatenating TCHAR

Tags: c++, tchar

I recently learned of the ## functionality that i can define in the beginning of my code. I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#define paste(x,y) *x##*y

int main()
{

TCHAR *pcCommPort = "COM";
TCHAR *num = "5";

cout << paste(pcCommPort,num);
return 0;
}
```

and i keep getting the following error:

```
expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type
```

it's not liking the fact that i'm using pointers in my "define paste" line. Without any pointers, it'll just return the variable "pcCommPort5." what I want is "COM5."

I've tried _tcscat, strcat, strcat_s, visual studio didn't like any of these....

Comment: Don't use the preprocessor if you don't have to. It executes before normal compilation (as hinted by its name), not at runtime.

Comment: `_tcscat` should work, you just need to provide a writeable buffer of the proper size. Create a third variable as an array of `TCHAR`, use `_tcscpy` to copy the first string into it, then use `_tcscat` to add the second string. Or use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` instead and save yourself a lot of grief. Or forget about `TCHAR` entirely, since you'll probably never use it configured as `char`, and use `std::wstring`.

Comment: Oops, never mind that last part of my comment, since you're successfully assigning a normal `char` string to the variable you must be configured so `TCHAR` is `char`. That means you should use `std::string`.

Comment: `#include <string>`  You included this header, but failed to use any functionality defined in it.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, just use stringstream and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

`##` doesn't concatenate arbitrary things (especially not strings). What it does it is merges symbols together in the parser into a single symbol.

Let's remove one of those `*` to see what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TO_STRING_HELPER(x) #x
#define TO_STRING(x) TO_STRING_HELPER(x)
#define CONCAT(x, y) *x##y

int main() {
    char *pcCommPort = "COM";
    char *num = "5";
    std::cout << TO_STRING(CONCAT(pcCommPort, num)) << std::endl;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/ytWkGj):

> ```
> *pcCommPortnum
> ```

What `CONCAT` does in this code is:

1. Expand `x` into `pcCommPort` and `y` into `num`. This gives the expression `*pcCommPort##num`.
2. Concatenate the two symbols `pcCommPort` and `num` into one new symbol: `pcCommPortnum`. Now the expression is `*pcCommPortnum` (remember, that last part (`pcCommPortnum`) is all one symbol).
3. Finish evaluating the full macro as a `*` followed by the symbol `pcCommPortnum`. This becomes the expression `*pcCommPortnum`. Remember, those are two different symbols: `*` and `pcCommPortnum`. The two symbols just follow one after the other.

If we were to try to use `*x##*y`, what the compiler does is this:

1. Expand `x` into `pcCommPort` and `y` into `num`. This gives us the expression `*pcCommPort##*num`.
2. Concatenate the two symbols `pcCommPort` and `*` into one new symbol: `pcCommPort*`.
3. Here, the preprocessor hits an error: the single symbol `pcCommPort*` is not a valid preprocessing token. Remember, it's not two separate symbols at this point (it is *not* two symbols `pcCommPort` followed by `*`). It is *one* single symbol (which we call a [*token*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token)).

If you want to concatenate two strings, you're way better off using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). You can't* do what you're trying to do with the preprocessor.

<sub>*Note, though, that consecutive string literals will be merged together by the compiler (i.e. `"COM" "5"` will be merged into a single string `"COM5"` by the compiler). But this only works with string literals, so you'd have to `#define pcCommPort "COM"` and `#define num "5"`, at which point you could do `pcCommPort num` (without any further macros) and the compiler would evaluate it to the string `"COM5"`. But unless you really know what you're doing, you really should just use `std::string`.</sub>

Comment: That doesn't work. Just try `#define paste pcCommPort num`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: What do you mean "that doesn't work"? Of course it doesn't work. It's impossible to do what the OP wants with macros. Also, your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, sorry I thought `pcCommPort` and `num` were predefined macros

Comment: Cornstalks, clarification much appreciated!
|||
MrEricSir, how might I go about using stringstream library?
|||
Mark Ransom, I 've gotten as far as concatenating type TCHARs with string like such:
    TCHAR *A = "COM";
    TCHAR *B = "5";
    string C = A + B;
this does work. But I need to convert this back to a type TCHAR which I haven't had any luck with :(
|||
Regarding your previous suggestion using wstring, tscpy, and tcscat, i think I might need a step by step instruction for these, i've been meddling with those functions for quite a while noW >,<

Comment: @BenMarconi: You can do `std::string a = "COM";` and `std::string b = "5";` and `std::string c = a + b;`. If you need a `char*`, you can call [`c.c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str). If you want to use a `std::stringstream`, [this demo may help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str).